# When to honor keepalive

Tags: httpserver

I am working on a server and am wondering when it should honor the keep-alive in the header? If a client sends a request without or with incorrect authorization should the keep alive be honored after the 401 response is sent?

Broader question is: Is there a document or standard that shows which codes should honor the keep-alive and which ones shouldn't? i could see the 500 not honoring the keep-alive but perhaps still honoring the keep-alive on 400's.

Currently this is the logic being used:

```
if ((400 <= status) && (505 >= status)
{
    keep-alive = false;
}
else
{
    //Do not update keep alive leave as what client requested
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: That would be part of the HTTP protocol, the standard you're implementing by writing a web server. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html

Comment: Hi, Yes i have looked through the standard but it makes no reference (that i could find) specifically about when to and when not to honor the keep-alive flag in the http header

Comment: There are no spec-defined instances when you should not keep the persistent connection. You do not HAVE to honor keep-alive requests; you can deny one by simply sending a response without the keep-alive keyword in your headers. But if you intend to implement keep-alive, there's no reason to make exceptions for any status code. The spec doesn't ask you to, and your logic for doing so doesn't make sense to me. The response code of one status tells you nothing about the next request that might be made and what its response code will be.

Comment: Thanks @DanGrossman i think that is the answer i am looking for if you want to use that as the response would be happy to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most servers specify the connection type even though in HTTP/1.1 "Connection: close" is the default. The connection type is usually specified at the bottom of the header, even though it doesn't need to be. There is no convention for what sort of HTTP codes should alter the connection type.

You usually close the connection if it's a 4-- or a 5-- code, since you do not expect the user-agent (browser) to try to interface with the server until the user refreshes the webpage or tries to access another one. Keeping the connection open only makes it slightly faster when the client wants to access another resource on the server.

A lot of servers close the connection after every request. Note that if the user-agent specifies "Connection: close" in the header, whatever you may reply, the connection will always be closed.

Whenever you specify to close the connection, the client will expect you to close the connection, this header is only to tell whatever is at the end of Socket what you're up to.